# Does the triangle inequality hold for a function that gives the number of nonzero entries of a finite-dimensional vector?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $x=(x_1,...x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite-dimensional vector. Let $f(x)$ be a function that gives the number of nonzero entries of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the number of $i$ such that $x_i \ne 0$ for $i=1,...n$. How to show the triangle inequality holds or not, i.e.

\begin{align*}
f(x+y) \le f(x) + f(y) \qquad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}

I think that is equivalent to show if $f$ can be a norm, because the properties of a norm explicitly hold true besides the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the triangle inequality holds.

If $x_i + y_i \neq 0$, then one of $x_i$ or $y_i$ has to be $\neq 0$. Therefore each nonzero component of the vector $x+y$ yields a nonzero component of $x$ or $y$ (or both). Hence $$f(x+y) \leq f(x) + f(y).$$

Comment: Yes, but I think the homogeneity does NOT hold because $f(\lambda x) \ne |\lambda| f(x)$ for any nonzero $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, thus $f$ cannot be a norm. Right?

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie Yes, rescaling the nonzero entries of a vector won't change the number of nonzero entries, indeed!